# Finding coordinates of an outer circle given a known angle and an inner circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to find a general approach to calculating the coordinates of a point on a circle given a point, the angle that a line makes connecting those two points, and the general equation of two circles. This diagram illustrates what is happening: [image: Diagram of Problem]

1. equation of circle S: $\ x^2+y^2=r^2$
2. equation of circle L: $\ x^2+y^2=R^2$

There are two circles L and S centered around point A, the origin. The radius of circle S is smaller than circle L. There is point B on circle S and point C on circle L. A line connects points B and C. The coordinates of point B are known as well as the angle theta that the line makes to the y-axis. What are the coordinates of point C where the line intersects circle L? (Thank you if anyone responds to help in any way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $B=(x_B,y_B)$, let $\cos\phi=\frac{x_B}{r}$ and $\sin\phi=\frac{y_B}{r}$ ($\phi$ is the angle of $AB$ measured counter-clockwise from the $x$-axis). Let $\theta$ be the angle of $BC$ measured counter-clockwise from $AB$.

The gradient of $BC$ is $$\tan{(\phi+\theta)} = \frac{\tan\phi+\tan\theta}{1-\tan\phi\tan\theta} = \frac{\sin\phi\cos\theta+\cos\phi\sin\theta}{\cos\phi\cos\theta-\sin\phi\sin\theta},$$ so the equation of $BC$ must be:

$$y = \frac{\sin\phi\cos\theta+\cos\phi\sin\theta}{\cos\phi\cos\theta-\sin\phi\sin\theta}(x-r\cos\phi)+r\sin\phi.$$

Point $C$ is the intersection point between this line and the circle $x^2+y^2=R^2$, so we can put those two into a system of equations and solve for  $x, y$. It will give two solution pairs; you have to pick one of them so that it  corresponds to $\theta$, not $\pi+\theta$.